# Parsing nested JSON into R List

Tags: r, json, data-processing

I have a pretty straight forward JSON object that I am trying to parse into a list of objects for downstream processing and use. The JSON structure is dynamic but here is an example of the structure I am trying to handle

```
json_string <- '{
  "instances": [
    {
      "feature_1": [
        { "col1":  "value1", "col2": "value2" },
        { "col1":  "value2", "col2":  "value3" },
        { "col1":  "value4", "col2":  "value5" }
      ],
      "feature_2": "raw_value",
      "feature_3": [ "list_value_1", "list_value_2"],
      "feature_4": {
        "feature_4_prop1": "prop_value_1",
        "feature_4_prop2": "prop_value_2"
      }
    },
    {
      "feature_1": [
        { "col1":  "value1", "col2": "value2" },
        { "col1":  "value2", "col2":  "value3" },
        { "col1":  "value4", "col2":  "value5" }
      ],
      "feature_2": "raw_value",
      "feature_3": [ "only_1_value"],
      "feature_4": {
        "feature_4_prop1": "prop_value_1",
        "feature_4_prop2": "prop_value_2"
      }
    }
  ]
}'

library(jsonlite)
parsed_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_string, simplifyDataFrame=TRUE, flatten=FALSE)
row <- parsed_data$instances[1,]

print("fin")
```

I want to be able to parse this and then obtain the `instances` inside of a list (or data.frame) i.e `parsed_data$instances`

When I view a single row / item of this list via
`row <- parsed_data$instances[1,]` I would like it to assume the following structure for each column.

`feature_1` is a data.table with the columns of `col_1, col2`.
`feature_2` is a raw value as indicated.
`feature_3` to be a list even if a single value
`feature_4` to be an object so that `row$feature_4` allows me to access the properties.

I have tried to do this via `jsonlite:fromJSON(json_data, simplifyDataFrame=TRUE, flatten=FALSE)` where flatten was set to false in case only 1 instance is set.

The issue is when I inspect a row or assign a row I see that `feature_1` is given to me as a list and in order to access the table itself I would have to do something like the following:

```
row <- parsed_data$instances[1,]
feature_1_table <- row[['feature_1']][[1]]
```

Is there a way that I can parse a JSON structure above to achieve my desired results?

**edit**: Including Screenshot of debugger to show that jsonlite is not doing this out of the box and that `feature_1` is showing as a property that is list of length 1.

[image]

Comment: when i run `sonlite:fromJSON(json_data)$instances` i get the table the exact format you are describing. Run your code again

Comment: @Onyambu I have edited the original post to include an image showing that the value of `feature_1` is a list that contains a table rather than just a table.

Comment: Note that a column can only contain tables if its wrapped in a list. All columns whose mode/type is not of base datatypes ie character, logical, numeric,raw must be encapsulated in a list